# Localstack + Jest: DynamoDB throws ResourceNotFoundException on deleteTable for an existing table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, idempotent, localstack, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm using [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) and `awslocal` to run the local AWS services inside a docker container.

Localstack is configured with a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Tests are written using Jest and AWS Node JS sdk for DynamoDB.

```js
'use strict';
const { dbClient, db } = require('../../adapters/dynamodb');

const dbSchema = {
    TableName: 'DUMMY',
    KeySchema: [
        {
            AttributeName: 'dummyId',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
            AttributeName: 'dummyId',
            AttributeType: 'S',
        },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 100,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 100,
    },
};

it('create DUMMY table', async () => {
    const { TableNames } = await db.listTables().promise();
    if (!TableNames.includes('DUMMY')) {
        const { TableDescription } = await db.createTable(dbSchema).promise();
        expect(TableDescription.TableName).toEqual('DUMMY');
    }
});
it('write/read to DUMMY table', async () => {
    await dbClient
        .put({
            TableName: 'DUMMY',
            Item: {
                dummyId: '123456',
                selectedIds: ['1', '2', '3'],
            },
        })
        .promise();

    const { Item } = await dbClient
        .get({
            TableName: 'DUMMY',
            Key: {
                dummyId: '123456',
            },
        })
        .promise();

    expect(Item.dummyId).toEqual('123456');
    expect(Item.selectedIds).toEqual(['1', '2', '3']);
});
it('delete DUMMY table', async () => {
    const { TableNames } = await db.listTables().promise();
    if (TableNames.includes('DUMMY')) {
        const result = await db.deleteTable({ TableName: 'DUMMY' }).promise();
        expect(result.TableDescription.TableName).toEqual('DUMMY');
    }
}, 25000);
```

Jest fails on the last test and dymanodb sdk throws the mentioned exception:

[image: Jest fail]

I tried using the [`awslocal`](https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local) cli to replicate this issue outside of jest and the same thing happens (used official [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-1.html) for cli command examples):

`awslocal dynamodb create-table --table-name MusicCollection --attribute-definitions AttributeName=Artist,AttributeType=S AttributeName=SongTitle,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=Artist,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=SongTitle,KeyType=RANGE --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1` **-> works!**

`awslocal dynamodb list-tables` **-> works! Logs out the list of existing tables:**
`{"TableNames": ["MusicCollection"]}`

`awslocal dynamodb delete-table --table-name MusicCollection`

...and I get the same exception:
`An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DeleteTable operation: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table`

And now the best part. Even though the exception is thrown, the table gets deleted:
[image]
[image]

Honestly, it's hard to come up with an explanation here, but I feel that there is something simple that I'm missing! Any help is appreciated <3

**UPDATE:**
It's not 100% confirmed yet, but in [DynamoDB docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/dynamodb-api.pdf) only the `deleteItem` is said to be idempotent, but not `deleteTable` which means that this could be the issue here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out I am having a similar issue. https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/4459

Comment: We didn't get past the idempotent thing with `deleteItem` which is the culprit here.